# Checking all the checkboxes at once but not in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I'm trying to learn how to use checkboxes more efficiently, and I found this example on how to accomplish something that I am trying to accomplish but I don't want to do it in XAML.

```
<CheckBox Content="Do Everything" IsChecked="{Binding DoEverything}" IsThreeState="True"/>
<CheckBox Content="Eat" IsChecked="{Binding DoEat}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
<CheckBox Content="Pray" IsChecked="{Binding DoPray}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
<CheckBox Content="Love" IsChecked="{Binding DoLove}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
```

So what it does is it checks all 3 if 1 is checked,

How do I accomplish this but with C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Put all these check boxes on a staklayout and give it a name let it be `Container`

then handle the `Do everything` check event as below:

```
 void check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox senderCheck = sender as CheckBox;
        if (senderCheck.Checked)
        {
            foreach (var c in Container.Children)
            {
                CheckBox check = c as CheckBox;
                if (check != null)
                {
                    if (radio.Id != senderCheck.Id)
                        check.Checked = true;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-commpatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFXamDataGrid"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Container">
            <CheckBox Content="Do Everything" IsThreeState="True"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Eat" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Pray" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Love" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (CheckBox check in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(Container))
            {
                // you can create your cases here
                // my case is all checkboxes checked
                check.IsChecked = true;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T) child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

USE CASE: All three if one is checked

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (CheckBox check in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(Container))
                {
                    if (check.IsChecked)
                       {
                           foreach (CheckBox check1 in FindVisualChildren<CheckBox>(Container))
                           {
                               check1.IsChecked = true;
                           }

                           break;
                       }
                }
            }
```